# jstree 3.0.0 contextmenu right click not working. Showing TypeError: vakata_context.element.html is not a function

Tags: javascript, contextmenu, jstree

My code is rendering tree, parent, child everything fine but right click contextmenu is not showing. Firebug shows error "TypeError: vakata_context.element.html is not a function". If I remove contextmenu plugin then it shows the default browser right click options. Here is the code.

```
jsjQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $('#pages-wrapper').jstree({
        'core' : {
            callback:{
                onchange:function(node,tree){
                    document.location='pages.php?action=edit&id='
                    +node.id.replace(/.*_/,'');
                },
                onmove:function(node){
                    var p=$.tree.focused().parent(node);
                    var new_order=[],nodes=node.parentNode.childNodes;
                    for(var i=0;i<nodes.length;++i)
                        new_order.push(nodes[i].id.replace(/.*_/,''));
                    $.getJSON('/ww.admin/pages/move_page.php?id='
                        +node.id.replace(/.*_/,'')+'&parent_id='
                        +(p==-1?0:p[0].id.replace(/.*_/,''))
                        +'&order='+new_order);
                }
            }
        },
        "plugins" : ["contextmenu"],
            'contextmenu':{
                'items':{
                    'create' : {
                        'label' : "Create Page",
                        'icon' : "create",
                        'visible' : function (NODE, TREE_OBJ) {
                            if(NODE.length != 1) return 0;
                            return TREE_OBJ.check("creatable", NODE);
                        },
                        'action':pages_add_subpage,
                        'separator_after' : true
                    },
                    'rename':false,
                    'remove':{
'label' : "Delete Page",
'icon' : "remove",
'visible' : function (NODE, TREE_OBJ) {
if(NODE.length != 1) return 0;
return TREE_OBJ.check("deletable", NODE);
},
'action':pages_delete,
'separator_after' : true
}
                }
            }
        });
        var div=$(  '<div><i>right-click for options</i><br /><br /></div>');
        $('<button>add main page</button>')
        .click(pages_add_main_page)
        .appendTo(div);
        div.appendTo('#pages-wrapper');
    });
function pages_add_main_page(){
pages_new(0);
}
function pages_new(p){
$('<form id="newpage_dialog" action="/ww.admin/pages.php" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="action" value="Insert Page Details" /><input type="hidden" name="special[1]" value="1" /><input type="hidden" name="parent" value="'+p+'" /><table><tr><th>Name</th><td><input name="name" /></td></tr><tr><th>Page Type</th><td><select name="type"><option value="0">normal</option></select></td></tr><tr><th>Associated Date</th><td><input name="associated_date" class="date-human" id="newpage_date" /></td></tr></table></form>')
.dialog({
    modal:true,
    buttons:{
        'Create Page': function() {
            $('#newpage_dialog').submit();
        },
    'Cancel': function() {
        $(this).dialog('destroy');
        $(this).remove();
        }
    }
});
$('#newpage_date').each(convert_date_to_human_readable);
return false;
}
function pages_add_subpage(node,tree){
var p=node[0].id.replace(/.*_/,'');
pages_new(p);
}
function pages_delete(node,tree){
if(!confirm(
"Are you sure you want to delete this page?"))return;
$.getJSON('/ww.admin/pages/delete.php?id='
+node[0].id.replace(/.*_/,''),function(){
document.location=document.location.toString();
});
}
```

Answer (score 26):

I had the same issue one week ago, adding this following css rule fixed my problem:

```
.vakata-context { 
     z-index:999 !important; 
}
```

Comment: Fixed it for me too.

Comment: Fixed for me too

Comment: I never expected this is related with css issue, fixed for me too though :)

Answer (score 5):

I can see my context menu behind the modal. So I fixed it by specifying a larger z-index than the modal. For example, my modal has `z-index: 10050` and I fixed the issue by doing the following:

```
.vakata-context { z-index:10052 !important; }
```